# What's the meaning of "Consumption hung low in the air"?

Tags: expressions

So, in Bojack Horseman, Season 1 Episode 9, Mr. Peanutbutter is making his toast (wedding) and at some point, he starts saying a story:

> It was winter in Prague, and the consumption hung low in the air.

I don't understand the expression "consumption hung low in the air" and I dont think there's a similar question here.

Comment: Means that TB was rampant, right there, in your face.

Comment: Have you tried looking up "consumption" in a dictionary?

Comment: Yes I have,and I wasn't sure if it had to do with tuberculosis or with the standard definition of "consumption".

Comment: "the consumption" is unlikely to mean anything else.

Comment: And the more standard meaning of consumption is usually followed by "of <something>". It wouldn't make sense to say "the consumption" without knowing what is being consumed.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.I would upvote but it seems like I can't do that yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was believed that consumption (modern name tuberculosis) and other diseases could be caused by *miasma*, hence "hung low in the air".